# Looking to build the Mathematical proof that $ Var(\hat{y}) = \sigma^2\textbf{H} $

Tags: mathematical-statistics, matrix

I'm looking to build the proof that

$$
Var(\hat{y}) = \sigma^2\textbf{H}
$$

So I was going down this road and seem to have gotten a bit confused:
$$
Var(\hat{y}) = \sigma^2\textbf{X} (\textbf{X}'\textbf{X})^{-1}\textbf{X}'\\
\mathrm{Var}(\hat{y}) = \mathrm{var}(X\hat{\beta})\\\\
= Var[X(X'X)^{-1} X'] var(y)
$$

Am I on the right track or where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the estimated parameters are:
$$\hat{\beta}=(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$
therefore,
$$\hat{y}=X\hat{\beta}=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$$
since $Var(AX)=AVar(X)A^T$, we can have:
\begin{align}
Var(\hat{y})&=Var(X(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty)\\
            &=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TVar(y)(X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)^T\\
            &={\sigma}^2X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T)\\
            &={\sigma}^2X\bbox[5px,#ffd,border:0.25px solid green]{(X^TX)^{-1}X^TX}(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\\
            &={\sigma}^2IX(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\\
            &={\sigma}^2H  
\end{align}
given $(X^TX)$ is Idempotent, $(AX)^T=X^TA^T$ and $H=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$.

Answer (score 1):

Moving a linear constant factor out of the variance involves multiplying by that factor twice.  So $\mathrm{var}[2Y] = 4\mathrm{var}[Y]$, and
$$ \mathrm{var}[X(X'X)^{-1}X'Y]= X(X'X)^{-1}X'\mathrm{var}[Y]X(X'X)^{-1}X'$$

Comment: (Worth noting that the second factor is transposed, but in this case $\mathbf{H} = \mathbf{H}^\text{T}$.)